# orderByChild() is not working in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the firebase data structure.

[image: Firebase datastructure]

Here I want to select all the node with value "stop" and delete them. I write this code but this is not working.

```
final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Query numberQuery = reference.child("numbers").orderByChild("stop");
numberQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
       for (DataSnapshot eachDataSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              map.put("/numbers/"+eachDataSnapShot.getKey(), null);
           }
       }
     }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
    });

    reference.updateChildren(map);
```

Actually, I did not get how to use query in firebase document. If there is any other method (without using query) tell me.

Comment: try to use `orderByValue()`

Comment: Thank for your answer, i just get it, i changed orderByChild("stop") to orderByValue().equalTo("stop") and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this, there was one problem that i was using `orderByChild()` but i had to use `orderByValue()` there. so i just changed `orderByChild("stop")` to `orderByValue().equalTo("stop")` and it worked.

```
Query numberQuery = reference.child("numbers").orderByValue().equalTo("stop");

numberQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for (DataSnapshot eachDataSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               map.put("/numbers/"+eachDataSnapShot.getKey(), null);
            }
            reference.updateChildren(map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `orderByValue()` and it will sort it this way :

1. Children with a null value for the specified child key come first.
2. Children with a value of false for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of false, they are sorted
   lexicographically by key.
3. Children with a value of true for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of true, they are sorted
   lexicographically by key.
4. Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If multiple children have the same numerical value for the
   specified child node, they are sorted by key.
5. Strings come after numbers and are sorted lexicographically in ascending order. If multiple children have the same value for the
   specified child node, they are ordered lexicographically by key.
6. Objects come last and are sorted lexicographically by key in ascending order.

check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order)